# vNext adding a reference from class library to a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Silly question perhaps but how do I add a reference from a class library to a web application?

1. I have the `ASP Net 5 RC1` update installed and ready to go.
2. Created a new website using the AspNet 5 Template[image]
3. Created a new class library
   [image]
4. The project.json file looks like this in the class library project

Problem I get is, I have tried adding a reference to the web project via the dependencies section and I get the error

**"The dependency Middleware 1.0.0 in project Middleware.Tests does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1. Middleware.Test"**

It is glaringly obvious from the message why this is failing however, I am struggling to understand how do I add this reference?

I have tried adding different framework versions like net50 but still no luck.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Middleware.Tests Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Foo Man" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Middleware": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit as requested the web project.json file:

```
{
  "commands": {    
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
  },
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Comment: try changing net451 to dnx451

Comment: would need to also see the web project.json to help more

Comment: @JoeAudette sorted it! Post as the answer please and I can close it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit Test class libraries are considered as "applications", the same as web apps and console apps, and applications should use the "dnx" monikers.

net451 would be correct for normal class libraries, but for unit test projects you should change it to dnx451

Note that this info is relevant only for RC1, in the next release there will be changes to the target monikers that make it easier to target multiple frameworks.

Comment: You should clarify that a unit tests library is considered as an "application" (same as console or asp.net core), and applications should use `dnx` moniker (or `dnxcore` for .NET Core). `net` moniker is for class libraries/packages only (`dotnet` for .NET Core)

Comment: yes, I wasn't 100% sure that his class library is a unit test class library other than he named it that. He doesn't say it is a unit test project in the question and his project.json shows no reference to xunit. But I suspect it is for unit testing and that is what I mean by "in some cases". I know that in my own projects class library with net451 works fine with web apps using dnx451.

Comment: I created a standard class library and added the xunit references after. I guess for this question I didn't put the entire details just the relevant information. But yes it is going to be a project to host my unit tests and have added xunit and the runner packages.

Comment: @JoeAudette: May be useful to add this informations into the answer for future readers, who may not read the comments